# display menu grouped by headings - array grouped by

Tags: php

I looked around for grouped by but i didn't find anything that either made sense or worked.

im trying to make a menu with grouped headings like salads/pizza/pasta etc
i got it to save to the database fine and i have it reading as an array( i think its called multidimensional[if you know what the dumped array is called properly please tell me id like to know].

here is my array dump

```
Array
(
    [heading] => Array
    (
        [0] => Salads
        [1] => Salads
        [2] => Pasta
    )

    [special] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )

    [item] => Array
    (
        [0] => Small Green
        [1] => Regular Caesar
        [2] => Baked Lasagna
    )

    [description] => Array
    (
        [0] => Grape tomatoes, onions, green peppers and cucumbers on the bed of crisp lettuce.
        [1] => Classic recipe with romaine lettuce and croutons
        [2] => With meat sauce, tomato vegetarian sauce or Alfredo sauce
    )

    [price] => Array
    (
        [0] => See Desc
        [1] => $5.99
        [2] => $9.69
    )

    [notes] => Array
    (
        [0] => Available in Small ($2.99), Regular ($5.99)
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )

    [submit_val] => Submit
)
```

im using this as the php to output the data(minus the mysql info)

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array['heading']); $i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="section"><?=$array['heading'][$i]; ?></td></tr>
    <tr>    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr>    <td class="selection"><b><?=$array['item'][$i]; ?>.
    </b>
    &nbsp;<i><?=$array['description'][$i]; ?></i><br>
    <SMALL><I><?=$array['special'][$i]; ?></I></SMALL><SMALL><?=$array['notes'][$i]; ?></SMALL>
    </td>
    <td class="selection" align="right" valign="top"><?=$array['price'][$i]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?

}// for i loop
```

here is what the menu looks like now [screenshot of menu](http://prntscr.com/1kblkk)

so how does one make it so the salads are in one heading and not two please, mind you i have multiple items in multiple headings(with same headings ie various pizzas etc)

Thank you in advance for any help you may provide

Comment: are you stuck with that structure for the array?

Comment: Thank you both for your help..i am most greatful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the last heading and do an if statement:

```
<?php
$last_heading = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($array['heading']); $i++) {
    if ($last_heading !== $array['heading'][$i]) { ?>
    <tr>    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="section"><?=$array['heading'][$i]; ?></td></tr>
    <?php $last_heading = $array['heading'][$i]; } // end if ?>
    <tr>    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr>    <td class="selection"><b><?=$array['item'][$i]; ?>.
    </b>
    &nbsp;<i><?=$array['description'][$i]; ?></i><br>
    <SMALL><I><?=$array['special'][$i]; ?></I></SMALL><SMALL><?=$array['notes'][$i]; ?></SMALL>
    </td>
    <td class="selection" align="right" valign="top"><?=$array['price'][$i]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?

}// for i loop
```

This does assume that all your headings will be in order together like that.

Comment: works right outa the box thank you see image here [link]http://prntscr.com/1kc1b3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are grouping your results by heading from the database, which will keep all items of the same heading together, then you could likely work it with the following:

```
<?php    
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array['heading']); $i++) {
        if($array['heading'][$i] != $array['heading'][$i-1]){ // Compare headings
?>
    <tr>    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="section"><?=$array['heading'][$i]; ?></td></tr>
<?php 
        } //endif compare 
?>
    <tr>    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>    <td class="selection"><b><?=$array['item'][$i]; ?>.</b>
    &nbsp;<i><?=$array['description'][$i]; ?></i><br>
    <SMALL><I><?=$array['special'][$i]; ?></I></SMALL><SMALL><?=$array['notes'][$i]; ?></SMALL>
    </td>
    <td class="selection" align="right" valign="top"><?=$array['price'][$i]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?

    }// for i loop
?>
```

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of the overall logic and for some reason decided to skip the first header. Oops!